# PHP: How to pass a string as an argument without wrapping it in quotes?

Tags: php

I have some HTML that I need to sometimes wrap in an anchor tag when a condition is met. I could do something like this:

```
<?php
    $html = '<div>my html</div>';
    if ($condition):
?>
    <a href="http://google.com"><?php echo $html ?></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $html ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

...but I don't want to have to wrap my html in quotes to turn it into a string. This is for two reasons: syntax highlighting goes away, and its harder to maintain.

How can I do something like the following?

```
<!-- pseudo code -->
<?php if ($condition): echo $this->wrapWithLinkTo('http://google.com', ?>
    <div>my html</div>
<?php ); endif; ?>
```

...so that the end result would be:

```
<!-- when $condition is true -->
<a href="http://google.com"><div>my html</div></a>

<!-- when $condition is false -->
<div>my html</div>
```

Comment: Short of putting the html into a seperate .html and include/requiring/file_get_contents on it, you'll have to use quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Output buffering](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)!

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div>my html</div>
<?php

$html = ob_get_clean();

if ($condition):
?>
    <a href="http://google.com"><?php echo $html ?></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $html ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

PHP's output buffering is used to capture output from PHP code, HTML mode, or anything, and then either store it to a variable and not output it to the client ([ob_get_clean()](http://us.php.net/ob_get_clean)), store it into a variable and also send it to the client([ob_get_flush()](http://us.php.net/ob_get_flush)), or do a whole bunch of other things with it! ([ob_* functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php))

Comment: Looks like you got in there first with that ;-)

Comment: Buffering, of course! Makes me angry that I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 5):

How about output buffering?

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div>my html</div>
<?php 
  $html = ob_get_clean();
  echo ($condition) ? $this->wrapWithLinkTo('http://google.com',$html) : $html;
?>
```

Comment: +1 for using the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)!

Comment: @Andrew Ternary is one of the most underused features of PHP. It's amazing how few people just don't seem to even know about it and use the (much less efficient) if/else construct to do stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.  Though this might still remove syntax highlighting.

```
$html = <<<END
<div>my html</div>
END;
```

Comment: Good idea! I don't know if it will show in his syntax coloring, however. Depends on the IDE...

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<?php if ($condition) : ?>
     <a href="http://google.com"><div>my html</div></a>
<?php else : ?>
    <div>my html</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```